# Extending post by email

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, email

Just putting my feelers out on this one, I need to be able to accept incoming emails and add  them as posts, however I want to be able to do a bit of processing first, for example I want to change the slug, prepend a string to the title etc.

Is there a way I can hook into the email function, change some data and then let it continue. I also might want to reject the email if it isn't sent from an approved domain (this will be a field in a custom post type).

Are my requirements achievable or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**Edit**

I have discovered the `save_post` hook, although it fires after the post has saved... not really what I'm looking for. Is there a hook that gets fired before a post is saved, giving me all the info about the post, especially where it's been created from.

**Edit 2**

Alternatively is there a way to add a post manually... so I handle the receiving of the email with my own code + cron, then have an API to create a new post with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the code of [postie *(plugin)*](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie), you'll probably find your answer.  In particular, see the filter sample files, and then trace backwards from there.  From the FAQ:

> **Can I add special text to the body of the post when using postie?**,
>
> Yes. You can create your own function, and use the postie_post filter. Two short examples are included in the filterPostie.php.sample file

Of note - per [this ticket:](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17147) post by email is slated to be dropped from WP core and switched over to a plugin, so you might be better-off switching to a plugin-based solution now, rather than building your functionality around the current core post by email functionality.